# A Dedekind domain without prime elements

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, factoring

We know examples of non Noetherian Prüfer domains, which do not contain any irreducible elements.

On the other hand, a Dedekind domain (not being a field) always contains irreducible elements since it is Noetherian and therefore atomic.

> Now my question is if there are Dedekind domains which do not contain prime elements. Equivalently, one could ask after a Dedekind domain without principal maximal ideals.

I can neither find a proof that every Dedekind domain has a principal maximal ideal nor a counterexample of one that has no such ideal.

Every help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to take a Dedekind domain that isn't a UFD and localize at a nonprincipal maximal ideal to get an example? i'm rather ignorant about commutative algebra, so I don't know if the number of generators is preserved or not.

Comment: Looks like no: the localization would be a local Dedekind ring, a discrete evaluation ring, hence a PID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3-X)$. This is a Dedekind domain, and its non-zero prime ideals are of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ with $b^2=a^3+a$.

I let you as an exercise to prove that these are not principal. (Hint. Show that $x-a$ and $y-b$ are irreducible in $R$.)

Comment: $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3+X)$ works as well.

Comment: Wonderful example. Thank you!

Comment: It should actually work for $R = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(f)$, for any $f \in  \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ such that the degree of $f$ in $x$ is bigger than 1 or the degree of $f$ in $y$ is bigger than 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: f irreducible, of course.

Comment: In such generality you don't know if the ring is integrally closed. For example, it is not if $f=x^2-y^3$.

Comment: Cool example!  I thought it must be possible.  I'd like to add this to [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com) and if you created an account there I'd be more than happy to associate your name with having suggested it.

Comment: I realize this must be totally trivial to you but what are good ways to reason it is Dedekind?  The closest I got was to prove it is $1$-dimensional and integrally closed, but that isn't easy for me either. Or perhaps you have a different geometric argument to suggest. Thanks

Comment: If I take a closer look, I also cannot see that it is integrally closed.

Comment: One can show that this ring is regular by using the Jacobian criterion. (This is Exercise 6.2, page 46, from Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*.) There is also an elementary approach, and I think I used it many times on this site; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678419/normalization-of-a-quotient-ring-of-polynomial-rings-reid-exercise-4-6). See also Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Example 4, page 65 for a general result.

Comment: Btw, to me the hardest part of this example is to prove the irreducibility of $x-a$ and $y-b$.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.